# Is there any way to require an annotation on a type parameter in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlinx.serialization

I am making a data structures that automatically persist data to the disk. To do this I am using kotlinx-serialization. Is there any way to require a generic type to have the @Serializabe annotation?

```
class PersistentList <@Serializable E> () : List<E> {...}
```

This example doesn't compile. Hopefully you understand what I mean. I want to constrain E to have the annotation. Any way to do that?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. I don't believe it's possible. Usually this stuff is done by defining interfaces on the relevant types. I wonder if `kotlinx-serialization`'s compiler plugin could generate a parent interface in addition to the serializer function

Comment: I seem to remember looking for that before, and I don't think it does. I don't think there's a way to enforce this unless it's possible to write some kind of lint rule, but I think that would have to be pretty sophisticated. I have no experience with custom lint rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `KSerializer` constructor parameter

You could add a `KSerializer` for `E` in the constructor of `PersistentList`.

```kotlin
class PersistentList<E>(
    elementSerializer: KSerializer<E>
) : List<E> { 
  // ... 
}
```

While more verbose, it has an advantage over adding an annotation to `E` - a custom serializer could be assigned, meaning that `PersistentList` could contain classes from external code that do not have the `@Serializable` annotation.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer

// Assume this class is from another library, meaning @Serializable cannot be added
data class SomeExternalData(
  val name: String
}

// Create a custom serializer for SomeExternalData
object SomeExternalDataSerializer : KSerializer<SomeExternalData> {
  // ...
}

fun main() {
  // Since a serializer is required, the `E` must be serializable
  val persistentList = PersistentList(SomeExternalDataSerializer)
}


class PersistentList< E: PersistentElement>(
  elementSerializer: KSerializer<E>,
) : List<E> {
  // ...
}
```

That's the only feasible way to ensure that `E` is serializable. Even an annotation couldn't do this!

#### `SerializersModule.serializer()`

To make it a little more automatic, you could use a [`SerializersModule`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#serializers-module), which has a function, [`serializer()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization.modules/-serializers-module/#-237127501%2FExtensions%2F-1349794498), that can fetch the serializer via reflection magic.

It's possible to create an extension function that works like `Json.encodeToString(...)`, that will automatically determine the serializer for a specific format.

```kotlin
/** Automatically determine the serializable type of [PersistentList] */
inline fun <reified T> SerialFormat.createPersistentList(): PersistentList<SomeData> =
    PersistentList(serializersModule.serializer())
```

However, this would not trigger any compile-time checks.

Here's a more complete example:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialFormat
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.ListSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.serializer

@Serializable
data class SomeData(
  val name: String
)

fun main() {
  val persistentList = Json.createPersistentList(listOf(
      SomeData("1"), SomeData("2"), SomeData("3"),
    ))

  println(persistentList)

  val encoded = Json.encodeToString(persistentList.listSerializer, persistentList.actualList)

  println(encoded)
}

class PersistentList<E>(
  elementSerializer: KSerializer<E>,
  val actualList: List<E>,
) : List<E> by actualList {
  val listSerializer = ListSerializer(elementSerializer)
}


inline fun <reified E> SerialFormat.createPersistentList(actualList: List<E>): PersistentList<E> =
  PersistentList(serializersModule.serializer(), actualList)
```